# How do you check if a UIImageView in an NSMutableDictionary Intersects with another UIImageView in same NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, ipad, drag-and-drop, uiimageview, nsmutabledictionary

I have 5 UIImageViews for each letter of the alphabet stored in an NSMutableDictionary. 5 instead of just 1, just in case a word they want to spell calls for more of the same letter.

I'm creating the letters like this...
http://pastie.org/2510574

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        char a = 'a';
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%d", a, i];
        alphabetVowelA = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(39, 104, 70, 70)];
        [alphabetVowelA setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]];
        alphabetVowelA.tag = i;
        [alphabetVowelA setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:alphabetVowelA];
        [letterDictionary setObject:alphabetVowelA forKey:key];
        [self.view addSubview:alphabetVowelA];
        [alphabetVowelA release];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        char b = 'b';
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%d", b, i];
        alphabetB = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 104, 70, 70)];
        [alphabetB setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"]];
        alphabetB.tag = i;
        [alphabetB setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:alphabetB];
        [letterDictionary setObject:alphabetB forKey:key];
        [self.view addSubview:alphabetB];
        [alphabetB release];
    }
```

With the code below, I'm trying to check to see if one of the letters intersects with another from the same dictionary. However, with my code, when I pan/drag one of the letter tiles then drop it, it prints an NSLog message for every key in the dictionary. Here is a sample of its output.

http://pastie.org/2511092

This output happens, even though none of the UIImageViews within the dictionary intersected. It actually happens after panning then dropping the first letter tile, before even picking up a second one for it to intersect with on drop. I can't figure out why. My pan: code is below.

http://pastie.org/2511054

```
- (void)panPiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:piece];


    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];

        CGRect startingPointFrame = CGRectMake(245, 428, 31, 20);
        [startingPoint setFrame:startingPointFrame];

        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
    }


    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

        NSArray *keys = [letterDictionary allKeys];

        int nKey = [keys count]; 
        for(int k1 = 0; k1 < nKey; ++ k1) { for(int k2 = k1 + 1; k2 < nKey; ++ k2)  { 
            if ( CGRectIntersectsRect( ((UIImageView*) [letterDictionary objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:k1]]).frame,  ((UIImageView*) [letterDictionary objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:k2]]).frame ) ) { 

                NSLog(@"k1: %i k2: %i",k1,k2);

            }
        }

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 5 `UIImageViews` per letter to your `NSDictionary`. All views of a letter are the same dimension at the same location. ie. all `A` views are the same size at the same place. Therefore, when you loop the dictionary checking for intersections, it makes sense that you would see a lot more intersections than you expect.

Perhaps what would make more sense for you is to change your problem statement from *see if one of the letters intersects with another from the same dictionary* to *see if the moved letter intersects with another active letter.*

You could track active letters by adding them to an `NSArray` the first time they are moved. Maybe you would also want to designate the top view for each letter an *active* view as well. Then, when you check for intersections, you only check your *active* letters.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense. Definitely a "duh" moment while reading your answer. :)